# How to display image view amongst stack view

Tags: swift, autolayout, snapkit

I am trying to display an image view to the right side of Root stack view. I have set the size and width but for some reason it’s not showing my guess is because the rootstock is in a vertical position. If I put the rootstock view in a horizontal position, the whole thing scatters. How can I fix this? Image below show how it looks like

[image]

This how it look like if stack view is in horizontal position.
[image]

```
class UserCell: UIView {

  
    var rootStack = UIStackView()
    var userInfoStackView = UIStackView()
    var subtitleStackView = UIStackView()
    var dateInfoStackView = UIStackView()
    var nameLabel = UILabel()
    var compCode = UILabel()
    var captionLabel = UILabel()
    var dateLabel2 = UILabel()
    var imageView = UIImageView()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = .white

        setUPViews()
        addComponents()
        layoutComponents()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }

    private func setUPViews(){
       
        rootStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        rootStack.alignment = .center
        rootStack.axis = .vertical
        rootStack.alignment = .leading
        rootStack.spacing = 3

        subtitleStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        subtitleStackView.spacing = 2

        
        dateInfoStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        dateInfoStackView.spacing = 2

        nameLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .bold)
        nameLabel.text = "Rolls Royce"
        
        compCode.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
        compCode.text = "(RTYD8NTV001)"

        captionLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 9, weight: .semibold)
        captionLabel.textColor = .darkGray
        captionLabel.text = "Best Customer Since 07/01/2019"
       
        dateLabel2.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .bold)
        dateLabel2.text = "July 2022"
        
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "print")
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        
    }
    private func addComponents() {
         rootStack.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        
         userInfoStackView.addArrangedSubview(nameLabel)
         userInfoStackView.addArrangedSubview(compCode)
         subtitleStackView.addArrangedSubview(captionLabel)
         
         dateInfoStackView.addArrangedSubview(dateLabel2)
         dateInfoStackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
         addSubview(rootStack)
      }
      private func layoutComponents() {
          
          rootStack.addArrangedSubview(userInfoStackView)
          rootStack.addArrangedSubview(subtitleStackView)
          rootStack.addArrangedSubview(dateInfoStackView)
         
          rootStack.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
              make.edges.equalToSuperview()
          }
          imageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
             make.width.height.equalTo(40)
          }
      }
        
}


let userCell = UserCell(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 60))
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = userCell
```

Comment: Please show a picture of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Nice. So personally I wouldn't use any stack views for this. I'd just lay it out with ordinary constraints.

Comment: I'll do it that way. I guess this is overkill

Comment: Or underkill, since to get the layout you have shown you would need two stack views, at which point it all starts to seem rather pointless.